# Reuse a function across multiple structs to satisfy an interface

Tags: go

Is there anyway that you can use the same function across multiple structs to satisfy an interface?

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
  Speak() string
}

type Dog struct {}

func (d Dog) Speak() string {
  return "Woof!"
}

type Wolf struct {}

func (w Wolf) Speak() string {
  return "HOWWWWWWWWL"
}

type Beagle struct {}

func (b Beagle) Speak() string {
  return "HOWWWWWWWWL"
}

type Cat struct {}

func (c Cat) Speak() string {
  return "Meow"
}

func main() {
    var a Animal
    a = Wolf{}
    fmt.Println(a.Speak())
}
```

Because Wolf and Beagle share the exact same function, is there anyway to write that function once, then share it between the two structs so that they both satisfy Animal?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can create a parent struct that is embedded by each of the animals that "howl". The parent struct implements the `Speak() string` method, which means `Wolf` and `Beagle` implement the `Animal` interface.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
  Speak() string
}

type Howlers struct {
}

func (h Howlers) Speak() string {
  return "HOWWWWWWWWL"
}

type Dog struct {}

func (d Dog) Speak() string {
  return "Woof!"
}

type Wolf struct {
    Howlers
}

type Beagle struct {
    Howlers
}

type Cat struct {}

func (c Cat) Speak() string {
  return "Meow"
}

func main() {
    var a Animal
    a = Wolf{}
    fmt.Println(a.Speak())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IMFnWdeweD

Comment: Is there anyway for the method on the embedded type to reference any fields on the struct that is embedding it?

Comment: Reflection can be used, i gues. But there would be very import any to controll and check everyone call , because this way increase possibility of run time error unfortunatelly...

Comment: sjmh it's not possible to write a method that can reference fields in a struct in which its receiver is embedded, as such a syntax doesn't exist and there's no clear way it should behave when *not* embedded in such a struct.

Comment: What a beautiful approach <3